# Pre-increment of variable in gcc compiler

Tags: pre-increment

The output is coming out to be 150. How?

```
    include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
    int j, i=3;
    j=(++i)*(++i)*(++i);
    cout<<j;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Could we stop providing/explaining this sort of quices/tutorials? There're *literally* hundreds of examples of *almost* this exact same question all over SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)